# Use google-maps places search and save place id for in mysql for rating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I might not be able to frame the questions as I may lack the use of "jargons" so please bear with me before flagging the question inappropriate.

I am trying to build a review system for schools. I am using google maps places search to fetch the markers. I am able to do this after reading google maps docs. My next step is to allow users to rate the schools and write reviews. This is where it gets tricky. I will try and explain this with a bit of an example. Kindly be patient.

1. User arrives at the search page.
2. Searches for "All schools in Kolkata"
3. Google maps display say 20 results per page with markers and on the left panel I display the details (Name, Address, Phone Number, Photo if any )
   ***along with most current review and rating***  (which is added via step 4)
4. The "Name" field is a hyperlink and when the user clicks on it, he/she can write reviews, leave comments and submit the data. I also have sql table which can store different attributes of this school. I would like to display additional data which is in my mysql table. Once submitted, this now becomes the most recent comment and review.

My Question is, is this feasible ? If yes, how do I store the place ID as an unique ID and display this along with google results. To sum up, I need to append google maps places with my information and display the result and modify it.

Please let me know if this is clear and I will try to reframe it. Appreciate your help

Comment: You want to store ratings of certain places for your review system? That can be done. I think you can use the placeId as primary key (if you want, if not you can still use what you're accustomed to). When retrieving from Places, if the placeId is part of the result, you can retrieve the ratings from your database and add it to the view you want.

Comment: Could you please brief how that can be achieved ? How will I join the google result (Name , Address, etc with my ratings and comments ), since the google result is from the web and my ratings in my sql server ? Please guide

Comment: The actual implementation will be up to you. The best I can do is share what I think your route will be.
 - when search result is retrieved, query in mysql if the item has a rating. If yes, render it on your view (along with other information you want).
 - when adding a review, since te item has the placeId, you can just call your insert method to persist it to your db.

Comment: Thank you and I do understand that I need to take care of the implementation part. However, How would I query in mysql (what should be the join key ) ?

Comment: That depends on how you design the tables you'll use. The most basic I can suggest you is to have a "Place" table that has the placeId, avgRating, other details etc. "User" will have a list of rated Places he did. Hope this leans you to the right route.